# What are the British and American expressions for “falso d’autore”?

Tags: phrase-requests

A [Falso d’autore](http://www.artribune.com/professioni-e-professionisti/diritto/2011/10/falsi-d%E2%80%99autore-e-copie-%E2%80%9Cad-arte%E2%80%9D/),  literally “author’s fake”,  has the following characteristics:

> Riproduzioni di opere note non solo pittoriche, ma più in generale figurative, eseguite da artisti contemporanei che ne rilasciano una certificazione di non autenticità e la cui vendita è perfettamente legale.

> (*Reproductions of not only famous paintings but more generally of figurative works made by contemporary artists who will release a non-authenticity  certificate and whose sale is perfectly legal.*)

A couple of examples:

[image: Dama con Ermellino, Leonardo Da Vinci]
Leonardo Da Vinci, falso d‘autore, Dama con Ermellino; from Accademiadeglialterati.

---

[image: Ragazza con turbante, Jan Vermeer]
Jan Vermeer, falso d’autore, Ragazza con turbante; from Accademiadeglialterati.

---

"Author’s fake", "copy", and "reproduction" are generic terms for these works, so what are the specific British and American-English definitions for “falso d’autore”?

Comment: Josh, would you mind first finding a hugely better translation of *Reproductions of not only famous paintings but more generally of figurative works made by contemporary artists who will release a non-authenticity certificate and whose sale is perfectly legal*.

Re-phrasing the whole Question would take a lot less time that waiting for anyo here to guess what it really means…

Comment: Why must every foreign expression have an English equivalent? What is the English equivalent to *objet d'art*? (Close is *work of art*, but it doesn't have the same force.)

Comment: @Clare 'objet d'art'. It appears without caveat in major dictionaries: it's English as well now.

Comment: @Clare - the “falsi d’autore” is a business in the art space which has been in place  for quite a few years, and it has been growing  quite consistently. Buyers are mainly foreigners (from an Italian perspective) , mainly  north Europeans  and Americans. I guess there is an expression they use to refer to these work of arts, or maybe they just use the Italian one.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin - not sure what you mean, in any case  a “falso d’autore” is: 1) a copy of a famous work of art (usually a painting or a sculpture). 2) the artist will release a non-authenticity certificate stating his name and the name of the work   reproduced. 3) all this will make the sale legally valid. 4) the falsi d’autore have a market of their own in which you can buy and sell them.

Comment: I would think *reproduction* would work, though there might be a specialized term.

Comment: "signed imitation/reproduction" or "signed fakes" might fit...

Comment: I would edit and include your explanation to Robbie Goodwin in your question, I suspect few are familiar with the Italian term.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - my impression is that they refuse to understand the concept. I’m pretty sure a lot of Americans buy falsi d’autore.

Comment: The comment you left for R.Goodwin is a good one, and I think posting 2 images which look original without providing the links, nor the names of the artists who copied these masterpieces is a missed opportunity. Maybe placing the original next to its copy and emphasizing it is not a forgery but a homage.

Comment: Please all look at https://www.pressreader.com/uk/the-daily-telegraph/20171017/281578060893931 which I promise I didn't fake.

There we see one of the most prestigious auction houses known to man running a sale specialising in *copycat versions versions of classic art* … but an article worthy of half a page in one of the most prestigious newspapers explains the merits of the *Master copy*  with no mention of *Falso d’autore* or *author’s fake*.

Whatever term Italians use can you find *Falso d’autore* or *author’s fake* literally translated into any other language?